# Fileupload saveas method doesn't overwrite

Tags: asp.net

I have a very simple requirement, there's a folder containing an image file, I have a form with only one upload field to select an image and save it with the same existing image name to overwrite it

```
protected void ChangeLogo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (!ImageUpload.HasFile)
        {
            ShowPopup("Logo Upload Canceled", "Please upload the image for the logo.", "stop");
        }            
        else //save the image
        {
            string logoPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/home/");
            string filename = "logo.png";

            ImageUpload.SaveAs(logoPath + filename);
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error:
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\images\home\logo.png' is denied
even though there's full access control on the folder but if i saved it with a different name it works, it only refuses to overwrite and I need to overwrite. I thought of first deleting the image then saving, but this is silly, why can't I overwrite?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Naive solution:

```
If(File.Exists(logoPath + filename))
    File.Delete(logoPath + filename);
ImageUpload.SaveAs(logoPath + filename);
```

Comment: Since `FileUpload` uses `FileMode.Create`, my hunch is that this won't work and that it's a permissions problem on the existing file.

Comment: Yes, always delete, you can't count on the file handles to release.  This also happens with File.IO.MoveFile vs Copy then Delete.  It's a underlying Win32 thing.

Comment: Yes Kirk, it turned out it was a permission problem the image to overwrite was marked as Read Only :S
It's now working after unchecking it.
Thanks All

Comment: As I consider ReadOnly flag as being an old pain, I usually handle it for getting rid of it. First instantiate a `FileInfo` on desired path, check its `Exists` property, and if exists, set its `IsReadOnly` property to false. And only then, I go on with my business.